# How to know if N is normal to the plane or not?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have N = <1 , -2 , 3 > and the plane 2x - 4y + 6z = 5
How do i know if N is normal to the plane or not? please be detailed with the answer as i'm very lost.

Comment: The normal should be perpendicular to the plane, so you can find two vectors that span the plane and check (using the dot product) that the normal is perpendicular to those vectors.

Comment: How do you find two vectors the span the plane?

Comment: By finding two independent solutions of the equation of the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** The normal of any plane $ax + by + cz = d$ is $(a,b,c)$, hence in this case $(2,-4,6)$.

Now, is your $N = (1, -2, 3)$ parallel to $(2, -4, 6)$?

Answer (score 0):

a
normal vector to  a graph of one  differentiable implicit function
$f$ in any point $M_0$ is the vector gradient  at that point that
is the vector $(f'_{x_i}(M_0))_i$ where $f'_{x_i}$ is the partial
derived relatively to the coordinate $x_i$.

So all affine planes is described by a type of equation $ax + by +
cz = d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are constant;  the gradient of the
implicit function $f (x, y, z) = ax + by + cz-d$; by a mental
calculation of this gradient  at any point it has  the coordinate
vector $(a, b, c)$. so in your case that is $(2,-4,6)$ and this
vector is parallel to any other vector $\lambda (2,-4,6)$ with
$\lambda\not=0$ , also the vector $(1,-2,6)=\frac12 (2,-4,6) $ is
a normal vector to this plane.

Answer (score -1):

In the equation for a plane the  coefficients of each of the coordinates tells you the direction that is perpendicular to the plane. You can tell if the vector given is perpendicular by measuring the angle between it and the perpendicular vector. How to do that is a matter of choice. I think easiest in this case is to note that 2*N is gives the coefficients so obviously N is parallel and thus perpendicular to the plane.